# Which default Database Systems come installed in Microsoft VS2010 Express?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, vb.net

Appreciate all advice 0n the following questions

1. Which database systems (Ms SQL 2008, MS SQL Compact, or others) comes installed with VS2010 Express edition.
2. SQL Server 2008 R2 Express is free, can we install and integrate with VS2010 Express?
3. How to uninstall those database already come installed?

---

I have installed VS2010 express on Windows 7; just VS2010 components (VB, C#, C++ and Web Developer) and without installing any other things like SQL Express. In the Console Panel->Program & Features' window, the installed list is shown below:

---

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup Support File
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Browser
- Microsoft SQL Server VSS Writer
- Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.4
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC2 - VWD Express 2010 Tools
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
- Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools
- Visual Studio 2010 Tools doe SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
- Web Deployment Tool
- Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express - ENU
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express - ENU
- Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express - ENU
- Microsoft Visual Visual Basic 2010 Express - ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008

---

As you can see, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (last line) and near the top, Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU and many of their related SQL components such as Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects are also installed. These are actually installed by installing VS2010 Express, but I have no idea how to use them or verify their valid existence from VS2010.

Also, do I have to uninstall them before I install SQL Server 2008 R2, which is the latest  version I believe? And what tool is needed to manage and create data source and tables?

Comment: Create a new Asp.net website. After that right click the website project in solution explorer and Add new item. In that window select SQL Server Database. It will ask you to add this to app_data folder...Click ok and then double-click on the *.mdf file created....It will open the database connection in server explorer on the left side along aside toolbox showing table and other tabs. **Try this and let me know where you get stuck or cant proceed**

Comment: @Tonygts We've associated this post to you, now you should be able to leave a comment under Pankaj's answer. please don't use Answer box for comments!

Comment: Yes, I can now add comment under your post. And I can also see the Add Comment box at Pankaj's post. Is this a new feature just added or was it a bug before?
Thanks

Comment: @tonygts it's been there since quite some time - you weren't logged in, so it wasn't available for you

Comment: No, I did log in. I mentioned before in my previous post (deleted). I'm certain I could see my ID:tonygts at the top of the page. I also brought up a strange phenomenon when I submitted a post with my log-in email, but it was rejected saying the email was already used - seems like a new registration process of some kind.

I posted a long msg under Pankaj, but it disappeared after his review based on the forum rule or what. I can't remember all the steps and details. I'll want to repost here for help to the issues, can you help to retrieve it so that I can use it get some solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Express doesn't come with any SQL Server Edition (either full or express). You will have to separately download [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) and install it. Don't worry about the integration, everything will be handled by the software. Install VS Express and then SQL Express.

You are ready to rock and roll !!

Comment: The above is accurate. However, you don't have to use SQL Server Express edition. You can use other free database such as MySQL as long as it has what is called "provider". VS comes with built in providers for SQL Server but for other databases, you need to get the provider and it is usually free.

Comment: Well he is basically concerned about MSSQL and its integration. So I didn't mentioned about other options. But thanks, your comment will add to the answer and his knowledge as a whole

Comment: Hello PanKaj,
I posted a long message following your instruction to create a database under the App_Data folder. Did you receive the message? Somehow the post has disappeared after your review based on the kind of rule here. Can you please respond and advise further from where I got stuck. I am following up this because you had asked me to try out your instruction and let you know the outcome, which I did as described in my previous post to you. Thanks. Awaiting your further advice.

Comment: @tonygts , I cant read any of your comment stating where you got stuck. Please tell me have you done what i said in the comment ?? If so, then tell me what happened

Comment: Yes, I did what you said. The forum had some problem; I could'nt add comment under your post, so I clicked the Edit link under your post to add my comment. Then, there was an alert saying the post would only visible to me until reviewed by the peer; I guess the peer is probably you or moderator perhaps. Seems like you didn't get to read my post; I've requested the moderator, Sathya, if he can retireve it, else I'll to do it all over again. It's not difficult to do, but it's kind of tedious to put it in words for posting. Thanks